# How to show image from drawable into center of the screen in Ionic

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework

I am new in **ionic framework**

```
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">NEWS</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  <img src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png">
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

How to set image into center from drawable.

like below

[image]

Thanks Advance. I have searched in google like this. But i will not getting proper answer. Please help me.